# Attaching picture to email link inside ArcGIS Online PopUp

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, url

I am using collector to gather data and attach images to that data using the camera function within the collector app. After collecting the feature, the user will then click on the feature to show the popUp (either in collector or on the web app on the PC). I configured the PopUp to have a link that opens the users email. Included in the email is a standardized summary of the attributes that were collected on that particular feature. I am looking for a way to attach the image that was captured during collection to the email. I'm assuming a link to the picture may not work because it resides on ESRI's secure cloud. Below is a screen shot of the Email To link in the configure attributes. Also in the popUp is the test image I am trying to attach. Any help would be amazing, as i assume there are others out there wondering the same thing.[image]